# How to get touch keyboard with text suggestion in windows 10 when not in tablet mode?

Tags: touch-keyboard

Under the windows settings for Typing, I enabled "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached".  But they keyboard option does not show up when not in tablet mode.

When the keyboard does show up in tablet mode, the text suggestion is not available, even though it is enabled in the settings for Typing.

I created a 1 minute video showing this problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rbYOV_Ci8s

How do I turn on touch keyboard when not in tablet mode?

Comment: That worked thank you!  You can add answer if you like and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **Touch Keyboard** button to always show in the Windows Taskbar, even when not in  **Tablet Mode**, you Right-click on any empty space in the taskbar and Select **Show Touch Keyboard Button** from the popout menu.

Like this:
[image]